# Orchard Search multiple fields with same term

Tags: lucene, content-management-system, orchardcms

I am trying to create a custom search module based on the Orchard.Search. I have created a custom field called keywords which I have successfully added to the index. I want to match content where the title, body or keywords match. Adding these using .WithField or passing a string array of fields tests for each field matching the term, I need these to return content if there is a match in any of the fields. I have included examples of how I am using both methods below.

Examples of how I am using the search builder:

```
var searchBuilder = Search()
    .WithField("type", "Cell").Mandatory().ExactMatch()
    .WithField("body", query)
    .WithField("title", query);
    .WithField("cell-keywords", query);


String Array FieldNames:
   string[] searchFields = new string[2] { "body", "title", "cell-keywords"};
            var searchBuilder = Search().WithField("type", "Cell").Mandatory().ExactMatch().Parse(searchFields, query, false);
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would fantastic :)

Answer (score 0):

A colleague wrote an article on this on his blog, should prove helpful http://breakoutdeveloper.com/orchard-cms/creating-an-advanced-search

Comment: Thanks Hazza, I have already looked through the source of that post and I still can't see a how to check make the search check the term against each field individually. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue!

The problem was when I was adding my keywords field to the index on the part handler. There were content items with NULL which was causing an error which I missed!!